# I can't show images in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-staticfiles

I don't know why I can't show images in my Django project ,
I am going throght a course and I came across to this problem,
the problem is that the program can't find the images that are stored in static/images folder and i don't know what is the problem excatly
I added anything that i thought is necessary
can you help me to solve this problem ???

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    objects = None
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='default.jpg')
    demo_link = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=2000)
    source_link = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=2000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Review(models.Model):
    VOTE = (
        ('up', 'Up Vote'),
        ('down', 'Down Vote'),
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=VOTE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("projects.urls"))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html file

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

<img src="{{obj.image.url}}">

{% for tag in obj.tag.all %}
    <span style="border:1px solid grey">{{tag}}</span>
{% endfor %}
<hr>

<h5>Description</h5>
<p>{{obj.description}}</p>


{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'devsearch.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'devsearch.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

views.py

```
def projects(request):
    objs = Project.objects.all()
    context = {"projects": objs}
    return render(request, 'projects/project.html', context)


def dynamic(request, text):
    obj = Project.objects.get(id=text)
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', {'obj': obj})


def createproject(request):
    form = ProjectForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('projects')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'projects/projectform.html', context)


def updateproject(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ProjectForm(instance=project)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('projects')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'projects/projectform.html', context)


def deleteproject(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project.delete()
        return redirect('projects')
    context = {'object': project}
    return render(request, 'projects/delete_project.html', context)
```

Traceback

```
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:36] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:36] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:37] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:37] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:38] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:38] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:38] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:25:38] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\projects\models.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2022 - 15:26:43
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2022 15:26:53] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:26:53] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\devsearch\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2022 - 15:27:15
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2022 15:27:16] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:27:16] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\devsearch\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2022 - 15:27:41
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CCnoor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\CCnoor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 35, in get_handler
    return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.base_url = urlparse(self.get_base_url())
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 30, in get_base_url
    utils.check_settings()
  File "F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 63, in check_settings
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: runserver can't serve media if MEDIA_URL is within STATIC_URL.
F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\devsearch\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2022 - 15:28:15
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:18] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:18] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:19] "GET /projects/1d3e224e-792a-4908-ba5b-7133653c67aa HTTP/1.1" 200 507
Not Found: /images/default.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:19] "GET /images/default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3267
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:50] "GET /admin/projects/project/51258114-993e-4d46-ac5d-6046a72723b0/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11828
[05/Sep/2022 15:28:50] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3343
[05/Sep/2022 15:29:01] "GET /projects/51258114-993e-4d46-ac5d-6046a72723b0 HTTP/1.1" 200 512
Not Found: /images/django-react-course.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:29:01] "GET /images/django-react-course.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3303
[05/Sep/2022 15:29:09] "GET /projects/51258114-993e-4d46-ac5d-6046a72723b0 HTTP/1.1" 200 512
Not Found: /images/django-react-course.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:29:09] "GET /images/django-react-course.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3303
F:\tuts\Django\Exercises\Course\first_project\devsearch\devsearch\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 05, 2022 - 15:30:12
Django version 4.1, using settings 'devsearch.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Sep/2022 15:30:15] "GET /projects/51258114-993e-4d46-ac5d-6046a72723b0 HTTP/1.1" 200 512
Not Found: /images/django-react-course.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:30:15] "GET /images/django-react-course.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3303
[05/Sep/2022 15:30:16] "GET /projects/51258114-993e-4d46-ac5d-6046a72723b0 HTTP/1.1" 200 512
Not Found: /images/django-react-course.jpg
[05/Sep/2022 15:30:16] "GET /images/dj
```

[image]

Comment: `{{obj.image.url}}` - this is for **media** files. Not static. By placing **media** files under `static` folder you have confused yourself and it's unclear how to help you. So do you want to show **static** file which is a part of your project or **media** file which is _data_ and is supposed to be uploaded by project users?

Comment: in static folder I have images folder that contains the images and SVGs and styles folder that contains the CSS file 
what should I do

Comment: Please show your folder structure and point to the place where default.jpg is stored

Comment: `I have images folder` for images uploaded by users of your app or for images which are part of your project sources, "constant" images?

Comment: I add the screen shot of the whole project folders structure in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help at least upcoming error finder's
after you host it to production that time you might change
DEBUG = False
That time you might end up with some error as the image from database might not be visible.
so that

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
.....
]
# solution
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` you must add `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`.

Also in top of your `template` you must add `{% load static %}`

Comment: It shold be `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}` it was removed in ***[Django-version 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/)***

Comment: Oh It has been long time since I used django, I will edit the answer, thanks for the info.

Comment: If the file is a media file then there is no need to load anything for static files. If the file is static then MEDIA_ROOT has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are two options:

#### default.jpg is a STATIC file

In such a case this is not correct way to show it

```
<img src="{{obj.image.url}}">
```

a possible way to go is something like this

```
{% load static %}

{% if obj.image %}
<img src="{{obj.image.url}}">
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'images/default.jpg' }">
{% endif %}
```

and remove default from the model definition `image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='default.jpg')` - let it be null.
Note, also you might want to define ImageField's option [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to better manage your media files.

In this option these settings control behavior:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

[STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) is currently misused here: no reason to mark the same dir twice as a static files target folder **where to** they must be collected during `collectstatic` command execution and one of the source folders **where from** they must be collected (this is what is STATICFILES_DIRS for).

#### default.jpg is a MEDIA file

Then the template is OK. And these settings control behavior:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-MEDIA_ROOT) is misused here: it is not supposed to point to the same directory where *static* files are stored. *Media* files are files uploaded while using your app by users (or admins). You don't know how many files, how small or big, how named they will be. Whilst *static* are a part of your project, part of your sources. So if you put both into one folder then users may be able to overwrite your css, js and jpg files, you will probably have troubles while deploying your project. Cleaning or renaming the directory will not be an option any more - user files are there. Some problems with backups, migration, sharding and so one will appear.

And in this case your `default.jpg` is stored at wrong place. Now you have to put it to user files directory (somewhere inside MEDIA_ROOT) and keep in mind that it will not be deployed as you deploy your project to different server.

Hovewer you can work this case out via symlinks or aliases in your Nginx config - because in the end both static and media files ["must" be served by a webserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/), not by Django app.

Comment: I fount the problem it was because of this line

Comment: urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_ROOT, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
I had to change ROOT to URl in the first parameter

Comment: Yes, and I did not notice that, copy-pasted into the answer. Updated my text as well.